# Access express response data client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

In my express router I check if the data inserted on a form are valid then if they are I render another page passing form data. I would like to access the data I pass client-side. On the `chat.ejs` view I have a `chatroom.js` client file, I want to access the data there without having to access them in a script tag.
I thought about using Ajax but the only answer I found here on StackOverflow was marked as wrong, so how do I go about that?

**router.js**

```
module.exports=function(app) {
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator');
    const {matchedData} = require('express-validator/filter');



    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.render('index', {
            data: {},
            errors: {}
        })
    });

    router.post('/enter', [
        check('username')
            .isLength({min: 1})
            .withMessage('Username is required').trim(),
        check('room')//implement personalized check
    ], (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.render('index', {
                data: req.body,
                errors: errors.mapped()
            })
        }
        else {
            const data = matchedData(req);

            return res.render('chat',{
                user: data.username,
                room:data.room
            })


        }
    });





    return router;




    //MOVE TO SUPPORT
    function find(name) {
        return 1;
    }

}
```

there is really nothing client-side so far so It seems useless just posting my views. Alternatively, I could use Ajax on client.ejs to handle the form submission but I would like to keep this clean and handle the routing with the router file.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating two global variables in a script tag for my index.ejs page like this

```
  <script>
    var user = <%- JSON.stringify( user ) %>
    var room = <%- JSON.stringify(room)%>;
</script>
```

and then I could access them in the chatroom.js file linked below